# Disable reporting all errors with error_reporting

Tags: php, debugging, error-handling

Is it acceptable to use

```
error_reporting(0);
```

to disable reporting of any kind of error (for production)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is absolutely valid: see the list of error_reporting below:

```
<?php

// Turn off all error reporting
error_reporting(0);

// Report simple running errors
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);

// Reporting E_NOTICE can be good too (to report uninitialized
// variables or catch variable name misspellings ...)
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_NOTICE);

// Report all errors except E_NOTICE
// This is the default value set in php.ini
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

// Report all PHP errors (see changelog)
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// Report all PHP errors
error_reporting(-1);

// Same as error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);

?>
```

Comment: I wonder then why Laravel framework is "turning off PHP's error reporting" with `error_reporting(-1);` https://github.com/ConnorAtherton/laravel-auth-skeleton/blob/master/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/start.php

Comment: The reason is stated in the comment just above the definition: framework handles it.

Answer (score 1):

You should have error reporting on so you can debug any issues on your production servers.

To prevent users from seeing errors, just disable displaying of errors:

```
ini_set("display_errors", 0);
```